# How to use essential oils in DIY cleaning solutions for laminate floors to mask the scent of vinegar?

Tags: flooring, cleaning, laminate-floor

I recently created a very effective and non-toxic cleaning solution for my home using 1 part vinegar, 2 parts water, and a few drops of rubbing alcohol. It's incredibly effective on laminate floors, but the vinegar scent is overpowering. I've heard that adding essential oil or citrus rinds may be helpful, but have I no experience using essential oils. Which kind of essential oils are effective in masking the vinegar scent? Will the essential oils leave an "oily" residue or damage laminate floors? How many drops does one add to a standard spray bottle?

FYI, they are Pergo wood laminate flooring, fairly large planks.

Comment: Do you like peppermint?  Peppermint oil is popular, ~5 drops per 16oz, at that concentration it shouldn't leave any residue, but not sure how effectively it would offset that much vinegar. Lemon is also popular.

Comment: Vinegar is not effective for removing greasy residue; don't use it. Distilled vinegar is sometimes used to disinfect counter tops which have already been cleaned. I suppose the counter is then wiped with a clean wet rag to get rid of the vinegar. The active ingredient in vinegar is, of course, acetic acid. What kind of laminate floor is this?

Comment: I would use warm water with a small amount of dish washing detergent or floor cleaning detergent. If you are concerned about detergent residue (say in an area where a toddler crawls),  go over the floor after the detergent with a damp mop and tap water, but honestly this is not necessary.  Also a few drops of rubbing alcohol in a bucket will do nothing.

Comment: The term "essential oils" is a marketing term for certain oils touted as nutriceuticals. I am not aware of its use in legitimate biochemistry or nutrition. The term "essential amino acids" is a legitimate term referring to the amino acids (from proteins in the diet) that a given species requires in the diet. This varies between species. Likewise there are "essential fatty acids", but this is not related to the unproven and surely false claims made for the chemical substances called "essential oils." These are essential in that they are essential for the sellers' bank accounts.

Comment: @JimStewart an "essential oil" is an oil extracted by distillation or cold press from plant material, that retains the original "essence" and/or scent   The term pre-dates modern marketing, going back 5000 years or more.

Comment: Try diluting the vinegar more.  A brief search on the web suggests up to 1/2 cup of vinegar per **gallon** of water; others say only one cap-ful per 3 gallons.  In addition to mitigating the smell, I'd think that diluting the acidic part of your solution would better preserve the wear layer on your laminate.

Comment: There are some cases where a miniscule amount of a material in a mixture makes a difference, but these are generally cases where the added material is used as a tracer. If the added material is supposed to be an active ingredient, then trace amounts will not do, except in the rare cases that the ingredient has a specific effect, like certain hormones or certain neurotoxins.  Acetic acid is not in that category.